# Attempt to call global (a nil value) - when saving tables to a file with Lua

Tags: lua

I'm using this (old) Lua module to save and access tables from local files (if there is a better way, please shout I'm not invested) -- https://github.com/gideros/table.save/blob/master/table.save-0.94.lua

It's been working great, but now I'm trying to save key value pairs I'm getting the error:

> attempt to call global `exportstring` (a nil value)

I'm new to Lua. The error is on line 108 on that file I linked to. Any ideas?

I've tried creating blank tables, or basic tables without key value pairs, this works fine. It's when I come to insert strings the issues arise.

This will work:

```
local myTable = {}
myTable[0] = 2
inputOutputTable.save(myTable, "testytesty")
local testy = inputOutputTable.load("testytesty")
print("Testing 123... " .. testy[0])
```

However this wont:

```
local myTable = {}
myTable["welcome"] = "1"
```

I get : attempt to call global 'exportstring' (a nil value)

Expected results - it saves the table.
What happens - it throws the error.

Comment: I see "Lua 5.1 compatible" on that github page. What is your Lua version?

Comment: _VERSION says 5.1

Comment: You might want to abandon this. The code references http://lua-users.org/wiki/SaveTableToFile which references [TableSerialization](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization) which has loads of options

Comment: `exportstring` is some side function which is required (non-standard for lua).

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Perhaps you inadvertently introduced the problem when putting the functions in the `inputOutputTable` table instead of the `table` table? The scope of `exportstring` is controlled by a `do` `end` block, it is required by both the save and load functions. A misplaced `end` could make it unavailable to one of the functions. (If you compiled/loaded the linked file as is, `exportstring` should not be a global access anyway.)

Comment: I discovered the issue was due to the embedded nature of the hardware I'm working with. In the end I bit the bullet and rolled my own version based upon the file I shared. It's working, and I'll share once I'm able.